# Compiling x264 for iOS 5

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

I'm trying to compile the latest version of libx264 to iOS 5 arm.

In mid-2010, the Gabriel script for building worked.

It doesn't anymore.

It says "No working C compiler found."

Can anyone give me straight answer?
It's 2012 and no one in google seems to have compiled it.

Comment: Be careful about making it available to the public if you don't have the appropriate licence...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams what do you mean ?

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**
I've added the needed files to the github repository below.
https://github.com/rodisbored/ffmpeg_x264_iOS5_build

I took gabriel's script and modified it.  I've been meaning to post the complete script online, but here's the part(s) you need.  Pop it into Gabriel's script.  This works with XCode 4.2.  I haven't updated to 4.3 to test whether the path names are still valid, but I think you can figure out where to update from the below.

For armv6

CC=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc ./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk --prefix='dist' --extra-cflags='-arch armv6' --extra-ldflags='-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system -arch armv6' --enable-pic --disable-asm --enable-static

For armv7

CC=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc ./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk --prefix='dist' --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' --extra-ldflags='-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/system -arch armv7' --enable-pic --enable-static

To link these to ffmpeg, make sure you put the path of the library and and headers into the --extra-cflags and --extra-ldflags.  If you don't, it'll complain about not finding the libx264 library.  The below is what you need to turn this all on.

```
--enable-libx264 \
--enable-encoder=libx264 \
--enable-encoder=libx264rgb \
--enable-gpl
```

Comment: Does your app can be released to AppStore ?

Comment: An app compiled with ffmpeg and the --enable-gpl option is not compatible with the iTunes app store.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can try these lines:

```
# you are now outside x264 dir.

export SDKVERSION="6.1"

cd x264

make clean

CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
    ./configure \
        --host=arm-apple-darwin \
        --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}.sdk \
        --prefix=build/armv7s \
        --extra-cflags='-arch armv7s' \
        --extra-ldflags="-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${SDKVERSION}.sdk/usr/lib/system -arch armv7s" \
        --enable-pic --enable-static

# ok now, you get the right Makefile.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the Gabriel/rodisbored `build_x264` script so that it works with Xcode 4.6 and iOS SDK 6.1. My version also builds the library such that it can run in the simulator. See https://github.com/kristopherjohnson/kxmovie/blob/master/build_x264

Unfortunately, I gave up on trying to fix the accompanying `build_ffmpeg_x264.sh` script, and instead updated the `Rakefile` from https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie.  So, to see my scripts for building x264 and FFmpeg, look at https://github.com/kristopherjohnson/kxmovie